# "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined" using message.attachments.first().url

Tags: discord.js

I want to get the URL of a posted attachment on Discord channel.
The URL gets logged but this error is thrown:

> ```js
> url = message.attachments.first().url;
>                                  ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
>     at Client.<anonymous> (C:\...\discord\tutbot\index.js:34:38)
> ```

This is my current code:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.channel.id != "595178696118108190") return;
    var content = message.content;

    var url;
    url = message.attachments.first().url;
    console.log("haha" + url);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no attachments with the message, `message.attachments` will be an empty [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection). [`Collection.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=first) will then return undefined. When you try to read the `url` property of the expected attachment, your error is thrown because it's undefined.

Check to make sure that there *are* attachments prior to reading expected properties.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if (message.channel.id !== "595178696118108190") return;

  if (message.attachments.size !== 0) { // Attachments are present.
    const firstAttachment = message.attachments.first();
    console.log(`haha ${firstAttachment.url}`);
  }
});
```